# What was Al-Jassasah, the beast mentioned in hadith 96, book 33, Tirmidhi?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation, dajjal

A Sahaba meets Dajjal is mentioned in [hadith 96, book 33, Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/96).

The Sahaba talks about a beast-like creature they see, when they asked him "who are you" he say "I am Al-Jassasah".

Is it explained/mentioned in the Qur'an or hadith as to what Al-Jassasah is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

الْجَسَّاسَةُ is derived from the root ج س س, which has a general meaning of investigating or spying.  This root is also used once in the Qur'an where Allah says, "وَلَا **تَجَسَّسُوا** وَلَا يَغْتَب بَّعْضُكُم بَعْضًا" and is usually translated as the verb "spy".

Lane's Lexicon has an entry for جَسَّاس, which is the masculine indefinite form of the same word, where it's described as "The lion that marks his prey with his claws" or "one that traverses a land".   As for Al-Jassasah, she is usually understood to be a spy for Al-Dajjal, who goes out to seek news and information to bring to him.

Comment: Isn't this the beast that will mark the believers towards the end of time?

Comment: No. That beast is called dabaat al-ard دَابَّة الأَرْض